Probability puzzle app: conditional probability
Suppose that, in the general population, mathematical and writing ability are independently and uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.
People attend university if and only if the sum of their writing and math abilities is larger than one. Among people who've attended university, what fraction have math ability above 0.9, i.e. in the top 10% of the general population?
Let $M$ denote mathematical ability and $U$ whether someone attends university. I calculate
$$P(M>0.9|U)=\frac{P(M>0.9\&U)}{P(U)}.$$
I think $P(U)=\frac12$, while $P(M>0.9\&U)=\int_{0.9}^1x dx=1-0.81$, so I conclude the answer is $2(1-0.81)$. My answer key claims the answer is $1-0.81$. Why?

$2(1-0.81)=0.38$ or $38%$ which is clearly too high as half the population seems to attend university and so no more than $20%$ of university attendees can be in the top $10%$ of the whole population in mathematics.

You are missing a $\frac12$ in the evaluation of the integral, since $\int x\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac12x^2$.
